# Will aspnetboilerplate support Server Side Blazor

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Any plans for aspnetboilerplate to support Blazor Server Side &/or Blazor Client Side

I asked this question last year and given that Server Side Blazor will be in production release in September. It would be really nice for the boilerplate guys to support Blazor. I am a fan of Aurelia as well but it seems that they don't want to do Aurelia as its not commonly used but its a lot better than Angular/React etc.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have a schedule yet for it. But we will work on Blazor UI for the new ABP framework (https://abp.io/) first, after its v1.0. Thump up if you want it: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/394
BTW, We've just released Angular UI for it: https://blog.abp.io/abp/ABP-v0-19-Release-With-New-Angular-UI

For current AspNet Boilerplate (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/), we haven't decided yet. Any community contribution would be appreciated.

Comment: Awesome guys! I am going to try and use Blazor with the app service layer at least